# MYSQL - to coding a PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just learning MYSQL / PHP. I'm having trouble with a query, it's working in myphpadmin:

```
select `email`, count(*) as count
from `table`
where `date` = "open"
group by `email`
order by `email`
```

I can't get it to work if I either write the mysql_query myself or use the php myphpadmin generates:

```
$sql = "select `email`, count(*) as count\
    . "from `table`\n"
    . "where `date` = \"open\"\n"
    . "group by `email`\n"
    . "order by `email`\n"
    . "";
```

The purpose is to query a three column table of  EMAIL, DATE, EVENT - where EVENT could be "open" or "bounce" and count the number of times a person opened an email.

Here's the rest of the file (I realize I should be using msqli, that's next on my list to figure out....):

```
<?php


$db_host = '123';
$db_user = '123';
$db_pwd = '123';

$database = '';
$table = 'test';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");



sql = "select `email`, count(*) as count\n"
    . "from `table`\n"
    . "where `date` = \"open\"\n"
    . "group by `email`\n"
    . "order by `email`\n"
    . "";



// sending query
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed 2");
}



echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>email</th>
<th>event</th>
<th>date</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['event'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
   }

echo "</table>\n";




mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

I just get the "Query to show fields from table failed 2" back - the query didn't work

The  '\n' in your query - was generated by myphpadmin (when I use the "generate php code" feature

I have a connection to the database, I just changed the value assigned to those variable so I wouldn't post them

I have the "$" in the $sql var in my file,  just didn't get it copied over here.

So,

When I replace this query with a simple one, it works fine, but when I try the more complected query, no luck. I assume it has to do with converting the mysql WHERE `date` = "open" into proper (escaped?) php....

---

I'm not sure what the procedure is when I sorta found my own problem = The biggest issue (of several). When I used the "generate PHP code" feature on myphpadmin it didn't keep the capital "E" in Email from the name of the column in the table...

Comment: why '\n' in your query ?

Comment: What do you mean by you can't get it to work? Is there an error? The wrong values returned? Nothing at all?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those newline characters might be the problem...

try

```
$sql = "select email, count(*) as count from table where date=\"open\" group by email order by email";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$database` variable is empty, and you are using that with your `mysql_select_db`

Answer (score 0):

1. sql var in line 19 (includes empty lines) is missing $.
2. what is the value of $result ? or is there error before that ?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using ' instead of `!

Also make sure that you have an active connection with your database. You're only checking IF the connection is possible, so I'm not sure if your actually keeping the connection intact.

Instead, you could do:

```
$connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: the back ticks are generated by phpmyadmin to surround table names. it's legit

Comment: Yeah I know, but sometimes that worked if I got some problems.